# Logout or Expire Session In Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

My question, Is this possible in vaadin to logout or expire session on page refresh and also expire user session if site is opened in another tab of same browser and redirect the user to login page.

Im using VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute() function

Answer (score 1):

I think by logout you mean removing some attribute from the session.

You can do this in the UI init method. It is called everytime a new tab is opened or F5 is pressed. Different Tabs in the same Browser share the same session.